# Grassmanians and Plucker embedding

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, combinatorial-geometry

Are the Grassmannians $G(r,n)$ and $G(n-r,n)$ isomorphic as projective varieties ? I can see that they have the same dimension $r(n-r)$. If they are isomorphic then I would like to see them isomorphic as images of their respective Plucker embedding.

Comment: Well if $V$ is a vector space, then $G(r,V)$ is isomorphic to $G(n-r,V^*)$.

Answer (score 5):

Yes they are. One way to see this is to note that every $r$ plane $W$ in $V \cong k^n$ gives an $n -r $ plane in $V^* \cong k^n$, by sending $W$ to the space of functionals vanishing on it.  You can probably check in local affine coordinates on the Grassmannian (the patches look like $Hom(k^r, k^{n -r})$) that this map is algebraic. This can be pictured as the orthogonal complement to a subspace.

Comment: I would prefer to see them isomorphic in terms of Plucker embedding and Plucker coordinates.

Comment: @MarkShiffor So you just send $[v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_r]\in G(r,V)$ to the $[w_1\wedge\cdots\wedge w_{n-r}]\in G(n-r,V^\ast)$ for which $w_i(v_j)=0$ for each $i,j$. No? Since the subspace of $V^\ast$ of functionals vanishing on $v_1,\cdots,v_r$ does not come with any canonical basis, there won't be formulae for $w_1,\cdots,w_{n-r}$ in terms of $v_1,\cdots,v_r$. Really coordinates don't get to the heart of the isomorphism, which is just taking orthogonal complements (or the analogous thing between $V$ and $V^\ast$).